# Virtual Address split in el2linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, virtualization, virtual-memory

According to [this slides](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/To%20EL2%20and%20Beyond_0.pdf), when Linux is running in EL1 the Virtual Address space is in two different page tables:

- User space in **TTBR0_EL1** (from *0x0* to *0x7f ffffffff*)
- Kernel space in  **TTBR1_EL1** (from *0xffffff80 00000000* to *0xffffffff ffffffff*) [both Linux Kernel & VM kernel?]

From what I understood, if Linux is running in EL2 the Virtual Address is still in two different page tables, but in this way:

- User space in **TTBR0_EL2** (from *0x0* to *0x3f ffffffff*)
- Linux kernel space in **TTBR0_EL2** (from *0x40 00000000* to *0x7f ffffffff*)
- VM kernel space in **TTBR1_EL2** (from *0xffffff80 00000000* to *0xffffffff ffffffff*)

Also, according to [ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100403_0200_00_en/lau1457341307460.html), **TTBR1_EL2** and **TTBR1_EL1** have the same content (which makes sense, because Linux running in EL2 should be able to access EL1 registers using *EL12 functions*)

Is this view of the Virtual Address space correct?